# Google Places API: deprecated types

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Google Places API in my project. Google deprecated the "establishment" type and the notice said that it still be available till 2017 but I can no longer access the data that my application is getting before the type is deprecated. Is there a way of fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: They seem to get superseded by more specific types, but I don't know which one replaces `establishment`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Pekka 웃